# MS Access 2003: ODBC File DSN to SQL Server: filter tables

Tags: sql-server, odbc, ms-access-2003, dsn

When linking a SQL Server (2012) table via an ODBC file DSN, is there any way to filter or limit which tables/views the user sees?

The default behavior seems to display every dbo object, including system ones.

Comment: Yes, but it's a heady topic. Are you using Windows or SQL Server authentication to connect? SQL Server has users and logins. The login is how you connect to the SQL Server; the user is how you connect to the database within the server. Permissions can be set at both login and user level. Without knowing more details, it sounds like the logins have default sysadmin access to the server which you will need to fix first before accomplishing what you want. [Database Engine Permissions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191291.aspx) for more help on this...

Comment: Thanks, I was hoping there was a something like a keyword that could be added to the DSN, but everything I'm finding indicates setting up users and permissions on the SQL server is required.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be done at the SQL Server side. Create user and grant tables/views permissions to user as needed:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188371(v=sql.110).aspx

ODBC data source definition has no options to restrict user's permissions.